# Validate an XML using Apache Spark

Tags: java, xml, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I know that Apache Spark was primarly developed to analyze unstructured data. However, I have to read and process a huge XML file (greater than 1GB) and I have to use Apache Spark as a requirement.

Googling a little, I found how an XML file can be read by a Spark process, using partitioning in a proper way. As it is described [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Parsing-a-large-XML-file-using-Spark-tp19239p19509.html), it can be used the `hadoop-streaming` library, such this:

```
val jobConf = new JobConf()
jobConf.set("stream.recordreader.class",
            "org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamXmlRecordReader")
jobConf.set("stream.recordreader.begin", "<page")
jobConf.set("stream.recordreader.end", "</page>")
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(jobConf, s"hdfs://$master:9000/data.xml") 

// Load documents, splitting wrt <page> tag.
val documents = sparkContext.hadoopRDD(jobConf, classOf[org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamInputFormat], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text])
```

Every chunk of information can then be processed in a Scala / Java object using `dom4j` or `JAXB` (more complex).

Now, the problem is the following: the XML file should be **validated**, before processing it. How can I do in a way that conforms to Spark? As far as I know, the `StreamXmlRecordReader` used to split the file does not perform any validation.

Comment: Is it 1 record per row?  If so you could skip the document element and parse each record separately.  Reduce to a tuple that contains any error information if a record failed to parse.

Comment: @SeanGlover, thank you for your response. Elements are not divided one per row, but using `StreamXmlRecordReader` it is possibile to cut the XML properly. The problem that I would process only valid XML.